# How to use media buttons for mplayer?

Tags: mplayer

How can I use my laptop's media buttons [Play/Pause, Next, Previous] to work with Mplayer? The XF86 buttons I think they're called.

Answer (score 4):

Create a named pipe like this:

`mkfifo ~/.mplayer/pipe`

Then, put the following line in `~/.mplayer/config`:

`input=file=/home/<username>/.mplayer/pipe`

or you can run `mplayer` with input argument:

`mplayer -input file=/home/<username>/.mplayer/pipe`

Now use System Setting->Keyboard->Shortcut and add a shortcut with the command parameter as (see `mplayer -input cmdlist` for the command list):

`echo "<mplayer command>" > /home/<username>/.mplayer/pipe`

e.g. `echo "pt_step 1" > /home/<username>/.mplayer/pipe` for *next track*.

and then assign a key to this shortcut.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but what happens when I'm not using MPlayer? Will my media buttons still work as normal?  Or will these keyboard shortcuts override the normal functions of them.

Comment: Nope! They would still `echo` commands to the pipe which will go wasted!

Comment: Hmm.. ok, I finally got around to trying this, and it doesn't seem to work.  Nothing I echo into the pipe does anything.  I have tried both .config, and with the arg pointing to the pipe, but still no luck.  version is *MPlayer svn r34540*. I just tried  *lsof* and it lists .mplayer/pipe is open by mplayer.

Comment: This works well. But how to enable the key without caring about active window. Like if I want to press a key while I am browsing but I want to act that key on Mplayer.